# Hosting reusable component definitions on remote server and use them as $ref in open api spec 3.0

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I am trying to do a POC on creating reusable components definitions and referencing them by `$ref` in OAS 3.0 (OpenAPI Specification 3.0). I tried below :

1. Downloaded the Swagger Editor on my local machine.
2. Created a file on my local machine that contains a common response that we want to reuse across multiple APIs.
3. Gave reference of that file in the spec - `"$ref": "file:///path of local directory/myreference.json"`

The output does not reflect the contents of the file that I have referenced. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Also wanted to know if suppose we host such specs on some repo like GitHub then will they resolve the references properly and can they be fetched by some CMS system to render the UI?

Appreciate any pointers on this issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi Helen, there are no errors on the console but it does not reflect the output in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Hej Santosh,

OpenAPI does not support absolute paths for locale filesystem references. From the [documention over at swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)
you can see that in your case you want to try the **Remote Reference** approach for **The element of the document located in another folder** scenario using a relative path to your specifications location:

> - **Local Reference** – `$ref: '#/definitions/myElement'` `#` means go to the root of the current document and then find elements definitions and myElement one after one.
> - **Remote Reference** – `$ref: 'document.json'` Uses the whole document located on the same server and in the same location.
>
>   - **The element of the document located on the same server** – `$ref: 'document.json#/myElement'`
>   - **The element of the document located in the parent folder** – `$ref: '../document.json#/myElement'`
>   - **The element of the document located in another folder** – `$ref: '../another-folder/document.json#/myElement'`
> - **URL Reference** – `$ref: 'http://path/to/your/resource'` Uses the whole document located on the different server.
>
>   - The specific element of the document stored on the different server – $ref: 'http://path/to/your/resource.json#myElement'
>       The document on the different server, which uses the same protocol (for example, HTTP or HTTPS) – $ref: '//anotherserver.com/files/example.json'

Comment: Hi @lordrhodos, Thank you for your reply. Can you please recommend a site that  can be used to host the reusable definition files?

Comment: you can use any publicly available hosting provider or reuse any domain you "*own*" for hosting the files. What I reccomend to you  is to make us of [speccy](http://speccy.io/)  to validate your specification. You will get beautiful documentation preview based on ReDoc as well.

Comment: can you please suggest if we can use bitbucket url of resource in $ref? if yes how to provide username and password required for basic authorization for accessing bitbucket url.

Answer (score 0):

While `$ref: file:///path` are valid JSON References<sup>[1]</sup>, you should not use them because they are **not portable**. Instead, use relative references such as `$ref: '../relative/path/to/file.yaml'` or similar, as suggested in [lordrhodos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459861/113116).

The reason why `$ref: file:///...` won't work in Swagger UI and Swagger Editor is they are web pages and use JavaScript to parse definitions, and **browsers deny access to `file:///` scheme from JavaScript for security reasons.**

> Can you please recommend a site that can be used to host the reusable definition files?

[SwaggerHub](https://app.swaggerhub.com) provides cloud hosting for OpenAPI definitions. Reusable components (schema definitions, responses, etc.) can be stored in so-called "domain" files and used across multiple API definitions.

*Disclosure: I work for the company that makes SwaggerHub*

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>According to the [JSON Reference Specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3):</sub>

> <sub>The "$ref" string value contains a URI [[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)],</sub>

<sub>and `file:///...` is a valid URI.</sub>